# Which CSS dialect is used in Material UI's `sx`-prop?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I found the following code snippet in the Material UI docs:

```js
<FormControl
  sx={{
    "& > :not(style)": { m: 1 },
    maxWidth: "100%",
    minWidth: "100%",
  }}
>
```

I assume `&` is not part of vanilla CSS.

The Material UI docs mention, that the `sx` prop lets me use a CSS-superset. But which CSS-dialect is used here specifically?

Comment: It *could* just be CSS, nesting is supported now. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting

Comment: `&` has been added as part of the "nested CSS" feature, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Nesting_selector (But it might still be, that this gets _compiled_ into something else by your setup, because browser support has been added only within the last year for most.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material UI uses emotion.sh internally since v5. Your question is regarding the emotion syntax which you can lookup on the libraries site. https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction.

& (the ampersand) character is basically the trigger for emotion to use selectors like &:hover, &:before, ...